# Swift iOS filemanager copy changes sqlite file

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsfilemanager

I have a routine that when my dataModelObject is initiate, its to copy myDataBase.sqlite file from the App Bundle folder, to the app document directory so that the app can use it. It only copies it if its not there, meaning in live environment it will not replace users existing db. The operation executes with no problem, however the database at the destination location is completely different than the database i designed. Has anyone else run into this, and might know what is causing this?

2 tables in said database one record only in one table with a weird number and a blob.

Comment: I do similar stuff at the start of my app, and I have no problem with my database.  Are you sure that the database going into the bundle, and which  you are copying over is what you think it is?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, i have confirmed that the file in the bundle points to the correct .sqlite file in the project folder.

Here is my routine that does the copy, does something stand out as bad? Should i use move instead?

```
class func copyFile(fileName: NSString) {
            let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName)
            println("copyFile fileName=\(fileName) to path=\(dbPath)")
            var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            var fromPath: String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
            if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {
                println("dB not found in document directory filemanager will copy this file from this path=\(fromPath) :::TO::: path=\(dbPath)")
                fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath!, toPath: dbPath, error: nil)
            } else {
                println("DID-NOT copy dB file, file allready exists at path:\(dbPath)")
            }

        }

class func getPath(fileName: String) -> String {
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    }
```

Comment: I was able to find the solution to this. The routine above was coping the file correctly however i have a camera app installed that i accidentally used to open the .sqlite file with which corrupted the db at that time. So i cleaned up the db added to my bundle again, then the copy worked fine.